# Android progress bar keeps spinning

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to use a progress bar (the normal one, not the horizontal one) as a compass of sorts, but for some reason the bar just keeps spinning without control. I've set the indeterminate to false, both in the xml and in the attached Java code, but it seems to do nothing.

This is the xml code for the View:

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/brujula"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="229dp"
        android:layout_height="507dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="91dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="91dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="135dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

The code I'm using to set it to false in Java too is

```
ProgressBar brujula = (ProgressBar) FindViewById(R.id.brujula);
brujula.setIndeterminate(false);
```

I have no idea whatsoever of why it keeps doing that, so any help at all will be appreciated

Comment: If I am correct, you can try this. If the work for which the progress bar is going to be completed in a definite time, you can attach a handler to it and set the max value for the progress bar with `brujula.setMax()` function. If I'm not correct please let me know.

Comment: sorry for not specifying, but yes, I already use the setMax() function, I set the max to 359 and the min to 0, so as to emulate that compass.

Comment: The circular progress bar only has drawables representing indeterminate state.

If you want to represent growing progress you'll need to use a custom implementation, find a library or use horizontal progress bar `style="?android:progressBarStyleHorizontal"`.

Comment: well that sucks. Thank you for the clarification, I'll have to look for a different way to do this

Answer (score 0):

hi try this if you want to show progressbar do like this.

```
ProgressBar brujula = (ProgressBar) FindViewById(R.id.brujula);
brujula.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and where you want to stop loading and want to hide progressbar use

```
brujula.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Thank you, but the question got solved in a comment (I don't know how to mark it as solved if it was a in a comment). What I want to do simply cannot be done, because the progress is permanently set to indeterminate. I do know how to play with visibility though, in fact I had 3 other views set as invisible at the same time

Comment: ok thats good to accept an answer please go through this link
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers